# How to create Jpa repository dynamically inside a class?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

How do I create and instantiate a jpa repository inside a class? I'm in a situation where I have to create repositories for different entities inside a generic class.

I could do that easily for Neo4j repositories like,

```
GraphRepository<T> graphRepository;

this.neo4jTemplate = new Neo4jTemplate(new RestGraphDatabase(
    "http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
this.graphRepository = neo4jTemplate.repositoryFor(domainClass);
```

For JpaRepository, I checked the documentation and found this,

```
RepositoryFactorySupport factory = … // Instantiate factory here
UserRepository repository = factory.getRepository(UserRepository.class);
```

I'm not sure how to instantiate factory in the above code.

Also Can't I create repository like I did for Neo4j, by specifying the domain class?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I finally got it working this way,

```
SimpleJpaRepository<User, Serializable> jpaRepository;
jpaRepository = new SimpleJpaRepository<User, Serializable>(
    User.class, entityManager);
```

With SimpleJpaRepository, I can use all repository methods.

```
jpaRepository.save(user);
```

Comment: where did you get entityManager?

Comment: You can do 
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

Answer (score 6):

Using `SimpleJpaRepository` you can only use the default methods provided by interface but not what you declare in your `UserRepository`

If you wanted to create instance of interface of your `UserRepository` you can use -

```
RepositoryFactorySupport factory = new JpaRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
UserRepository repository = factory.getRepository(UserRepository.class);
```

it will give you liberty to use custom methods also that was defined by you in `UserRepository`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your interface, you can do something similar.

1. Add a new class that implements your interface (in your case `UserRepository`) and extends `SimpleJpaRepository`.

```
private static class SimpleUserRepository<T, ID> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements UserRepository<T, ID> {
    public SimpleIRepository(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
        super(domainClass, em);
    }
}
```

2. Create and cast your new `JpaRepository`.

```
UserRepository<User, Long> userRepository = new SimpleUserRepository<>(User.class, em);
```

3. Use this repository with your `UserRepository` interface.

```
userRepository.save(user);
```