# List of CrudRepository items

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I need to make a query to number of databases. The number of databases can vary.

It looks convinient to have an ability to iterate them through a list.

Is it a good idea, or is it at least possible to have a list of repositories connected to different datasources or there is another better way?

I've already read [How to use 2 or more databases with spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362546/how-to-use-2-or-more-databases-with-spring)
. For implementing it I have to know the number of databases, but it can vary.

I tried:

```
@Entity
public class Member{}

public interface MemberRepository extends CrudRepository<Member, Long> {
}

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("myClass")
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    private MemberRepository memberRepository;
}

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("myClassHub")
public class MyClassHub {
    @Autowired
    private List<MyClass> myClasses;
}
```

This looks logical for me. But I cannot understand how to configure this list items.
Such configuration does not work.

application.yml

```
myClassHub:
  myClasses:
    -
      spring:
        datasource:
          url: jdbc:mysql://url
          username: username
          password: password
    -
      spring:
        datasource:
          url: jdbc:mysql://url
          username: username
          password: password
```

in pom.xml I have:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I also thought about using [AbstractRoutingDataSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html), but the architecture of classes will become too complicated and not logical.

Comment: I got a suggestion to try with SimpleJpaRepository. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116005/how-to-create-jpa-repository-dynamically-inside-a-class). Looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution.
The idea is to use SimpleJpaRepository instead of CrudRepository.
But it is a bit tricky.

My example:

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You need to configure unit in persistence.xml with transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="my-JPA" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Then you need a map with properties(url, driver, user, password...)
You can get them @Autowired or fill in runtime:

```
Map dbProperties;
dbProperties = new HashMap();
dbProperties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
dbProperties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://url/database");
dbProperties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "user");
dbProperties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "password");
```

EntityManager and EntityManagerFactory:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("my-JPA", dbProperties);
EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
```

And finally:

```
jpaRepository = new SimpleJpaRepository<Member, Long>( Member.class, entityManager);
```