# Wiring repositories using beans.xml for lots of implementations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have three interfaces going together a `CsvParser`, `DboMapper` and a `CrudRepository`. Now I have like 100 implementations of each of those and I want to wire them into a Map using beans.xml. Then whatever file I get I just ask for the corresponding parser, mapper and repository to do the job.

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="xxx" />
 <jpa:repositories base-package="xxx" />

 <util:map id="loaders" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
        <entry key="account-list.csv"><ref bean="accountListLoader" /></entry>
        <!-- more to come -->
    </util:map>
 <bean id="accountListLoader" class="xxx.etl.CsvFileLoader">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <bean class="xxx.model.implementations.accountlist.AccountListCsvParser" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <bean class="xxx.model.implementations.accountlist.AccountListMapper"/>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="2">
        <bean class="xxx.model.implementations.accountlist.AccountListRepositoryImpl" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

However the last bean is actually a CrudRepository and thus an interface which can not be instantiated. Can I somehow hand wire a JPA (mysql) repository?

Or is the a way to `@Autowire` something like that? I mean auto wiring tens of implementations of an interface into a map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I have ended up using a combination of `Applicationcontext#getBean` and a `SimpleJpaRepository` like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22342025/1298461)