# Spring cloud gcp DatastoreRepository intialize without autoconfig or annotations

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-datastore, spring-cloud-gcp

I am trying to use [gcp datastore sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/53df2d37a380b69b49688ddb558088fffc19b542/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-data-datastore-sample/src/main/java/com/example/DatastoreRepositoryExample.java#L47) but I would like initialize repository manually. 
Something like [SimpleJpaRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116005/how-to-create-jpa-repository-dynamically-inside-a-class) in another SO. Is it possible to initialize DatastoreRepository ?

Example with JPA repository one can simply do :

EmployeeRepository employeeRepository = new JpaRepositoryFactory(entityManager)
        .getRepository(EmployeeRepository.class);

entityManager can be injected via hibernate session factory. All entity classes can be registered to the registry of session factory.

Now , in order to initialize/register EmployeeRepository : 
public interface EmployeeRepository extends DatastoreRepository

Note: The environment where the code will run does not have auto-wiring/annotations support.

Comment: what do you mean with initializing DatastoreRepository manually? you mean creating a database and then the entities? if it is so, you can do it programmatically using the normal methods.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get it to work by using below :

```
DatastoreFactory datastoreFactory = new DefaultDatastoreFactory();
Supplier<Datastore> datastore = () -> datastoreFactory.create(DatastoreOptions.getDefaultInstance());


//Register Datastore Entity classes
DatastoreMappingContext datastoreMappingContext = new DatastoreMappingContext();
datastoreMappingContext.setInitialEntitySet(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(Employee.class)));

ObjectToKeyFactory objectToKeyFactory = new DatastoreServiceObjectToKeyFactory(datastore);

DatastoreEntityConverter datastoreEntityConverter = new DefaultDatastoreEntityConverter(datastoreMappingContext, objectToKeyFactory);
DatastoreOperations datastoreOperations = new DatastoreTemplate(datastore,datastoreEntityConverter, datastoreMappingContext, objectToKeyFactory);

EmployeeRepository employeeRepository  = new SimpleDatastoreRepository<>(datastoreOperations, Employee.class);
employeeRepository.count(); // findAll() etc
```