# Dynamically creating spring EnversRevisionRepository from a Java Class

Tags: java, spring-data, audit, revision, spring-data-envers

How does one create an `EnversRevisionRepository` dynamically given a Java Class object?

Thanks to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22342025/3771679 one can successfully create a `JpaRepository` dynamically, but I would like to achieve the same for a repository that is equivalent to:

```
public interface MyRevisionedRepository extends RevisionRepository<X,Y,Z>, JpaRepository<X,Y> {

}
```

Comment: Write Custom Annotation Processor.

Comment: Probably will need more detail than that.  The point of this question is not needing to create an interface definition at all so I'm not sure how a custom annotation processor would help.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data provides [`EnversRevisionRepositoryImpl`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-envers/blob/9f3147053ce200eb52e556ee37ae9c01a1a810d1/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/envers/repository/support/EnversRevisionRepositoryImpl.java) as the default [`RevisionRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/history/RevisionRepository.html?is-external=true) implementation.

As you can see in the repository constructor:

```java
    /**
     * Creates a new {@link EnversRevisionRepositoryImpl} using the given {@link JpaEntityInformation},
     * {@link RevisionEntityInformation} and {@link EntityManager}.
     *
     * @param entityInformation must not be {@literal null}.
     * @param revisionEntityInformation must not be {@literal null}.
     * @param entityManager must not be {@literal null}.
     */
    public EnversRevisionRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation,
            RevisionEntityInformation revisionEntityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {

        Assert.notNull(revisionEntityInformation, "RevisionEntityInformation must not be null!");

        this.entityInformation = entityInformation;
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
```

you need three things to create a new instance of that repository:

- An `EntityManager`, which you can easily obtain using `@PersistenceContext` or probably (I never tested it) by `@Autowiring`.
- A `JpaEntityInformation`. Following the example of [`SimpleJpaRepository`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/08c2acc0cfaa1d760818d7a22ee3079fe8285d5c/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L117):

```java
final JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation =
  JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(domainClass, em)
```

- A `RevisionEntityInformation`. It is curious, as the object is being asserted to not be null but actually it seems unused in the rest of the implementation code. Here, we can follow the example of [`EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-envers/blob/9f3147053ce200eb52e556ee37ae9c01a1a810d1/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/envers/repository/support/EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.java#L92-L95):

```java
final RevisionEntityInformation revisionEntityInformation =
  Optional.ofNullable(revisionEntityClass) //
    .filter(it -> !it.equals(DefaultRevisionEntity.class))//
    .<RevisionEntityInformation> map(ReflectionRevisionEntityInformation::new) //
    .orElseGet(DefaultRevisionEntityInformation::new);
```

`DefaultRevisionEntityInformation` is package scoped, but you can easily reproduce it:

```java
import org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity;
import org.springframework.data.repository.history.support.RevisionEntityInformation;

/**
 * {@link RevisionEntityInformation} for {@link DefaultRevisionEntity}.
 */
public class DefaultRevisionEntityInformation implements RevisionEntityInformation {

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.history.support.RevisionEntityInformation#getRevisionNumberType()
     */
    public Class<?> getRevisionNumberType() {
        return Integer.class;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.history.support.RevisionEntityInformation#isDefaultRevisionEntity()
     */
    public boolean isDefaultRevisionEntity() {
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.history.support.RevisionEntityInformation#getRevisionEntityClass()
     */
    public Class<?> getRevisionEntityClass() {
        return DefaultRevisionEntity.class;
    }
}
```

In summary:

```java
// Obtain a reference to the underlying EntityManager
final EntityManager entityManager = ...;
// Provide JpaEntityInformation
final JpaEntityInformation<User, ?> entityInformation =
  JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(User.class, entityManager);
// Provide RevisionEntityInformation. The solution is based on 
// DefaultRevisionEntity but you can provide your custom revision entity
// if appropriate
final RevisionEntityInformation revisionEntityInformation =
  new DefaultRevisionEntityInformation();
// Build your custom revision repository, for example:
final RevisionRepository userRevisionRepository =
  new EnversRevisionRepositoryImpl<User, Integer, DefaultRevisionEntity>(
    entityInformation, revisionEntityInformation, entityManager
  )
;
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks, haven’t tried it yet but will be needing it soon so fingers crossed and many thanks for your time.

Comment: You are welcome @GrowlingBadger. I hope it helps. Please, if you face any problem with the code, let me know, I will be glad to adapt it as required in order to provide you a proper solution.